# JavaScript regex validation issue with time format

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I try to validate a time valie with the following script but the second value does not validate for some reason. Is there anything wrong on my script ?

```
var timeFormat      =   /^([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})$/g;
var time_one        =   '00:00';
var time_two        =   '15:20';

if(timeFormat.test(time_one) == false)
{
    console.log('Time one is wrong');
}
else if(timeFormat.test(time_two) == false)
{
    console.log('Time two is wrong');
}
```

The above script returns always the **Time two is wrong** in my console. Also I have try to set the value of the **time_two** to '00:00' but again does not validate.

Is my regex wrong ?

**NOTE :** I also have try the following regex, but still with the same effect:

```
var timeFormat      =    /(\d{2}\:\d{2})/g;
```

Comment: Thanks every one for tha response !! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it comes from the "global" flag, try this instead :

```
var timeFormat = /^([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})$/;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results

Comment: Yes, also try `/^\d\d:\d\d$/`.

Comment: @wared thanks for your answer, that was the issue, now working normaly. I will up vote your answer in < 10'' :)

Comment: Good answer, but will allow invalid time values, such as 99:99.

Answer (score 1):

`test` will progress a global regexp by one match, and rewind when it gets to the end of the string.

```
var timeFormat      =   /^([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})$/g;
var time_one        =   '00:00';

timeFormat.test(time_one)  // => true   finds 00:00
timeFormat.test(time_one)  // => false  no more matches
timeFormat.test(time_one)  // => true   restarts and finds 00:00 again
```

So you need to lose the `g` flag in your scenario.

Comment: @Amadan You were a member of FlashFrance right ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

May I propose the following options:

```
/^[01]?\d:[0-5]\d( (am|pm))?$/i  // matches non-military time, e.g. 11:59 pm

/^[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d$/              // matches only military time, e.g. 23:59

/^[0-2]?\d:[0-5]\d( (am|pm))?$/i // matches either, but allows invalid values 
                                 // such as 23:59 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple with

```
/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$/
```

**output:**

```
12:12 -> OK
00:00 -> OK
23:59 -> OK
24:00 -> NG
12:60 -> NG
9:40 -> NG
```

Demo: https://regexr.com/40vuj